# Angular 2 add key and value to each array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, javascript-objects

I have array of objects :

```
array = [
  {name: 'name'},
  {name: 'name'},
  {name: 'name'},
  {name: 'name'},
]
```

I want to add key: '123' to each of them so it would be :

```
array = [
  {name: 'name', key: '123'},
  {name: 'name', key: '123'},
  {name: 'name', key: '123'},
  {name: 'name', key: '123'},
]
```

What I've tryed :

```
checked = false;
     this.editObj.forEach(item => item.push(this.checked))
```

> ERROR : item.push is not a function.

**But it isn't working. How to do it in the right way ?**

Comment: You want to modify the object within the array so you need to use `item["key"] = "123"`

Answer (score 3):

```
const arr = [
  {name: 'name'},
  {name: 'name'},
  {name: 'name'},
  {name: 'name'},
]

const arr2 = arr.map(x => ({...x , key: '123'}));
```

Comment: Mixing ES5 `var` with ES6 `...` (spread operator) is uncanny. Please use `const`

Answer (score 2):

you should do :

```
this.editObj.forEach(item => item["key"]= "123");
console.log(this.editObj);
```

Comment: this is returning an error :) 
`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Answer (score 2):

You can try with creating custom dictionary

```js
array = [
{name: 'name'},
{name: 'name'},
{name: 'name'},
{name: 'name'},
]

var dict = []; // create an empty dictionary
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 

  dict.push({
    key:   "123",
    value: array[i].name
  });
  

}
  console.log(dict);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because you use `.push()` on object, not on array.
Try this:

```
this.editObj.forEach(item => item["key"] = this.checked);
```

Comment: Look at  [no-return-assign](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-assign) rule.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT I know this rule, but it's a shorthand 1-liner

Comment: what about `this.editObj.forEach(item => (item["key"] = this.checked;));`

Answer (score 1):

In everything except IE11

*Creating a new array*

```js
const array = [{
    name: 'name',
  },
  {
    name: 'name',
  },
  {
    name: 'name',
  },
  {
    name: 'name',
  },
];

console.log(array.map(x => ({
  ...x,

  key: '123',
})));
```

*Updating existing array*

```js
const array = [{
    name: 'name',
  },
  {
    name: 'name',
  },
  {
    name: 'name',
  },
  {
    name: 'name',
  },
];

array.forEach((x) => {
  x.key = '123';
});

console.log(array);
```

---

In IE11

```js
var array = [{
    name: 'name',
  },
  {
    name: 'name',
  },
  {
    name: 'name',
  },
  {
    name: 'name',
  },
];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
  array[i].key = '123';
}

console.log(array);
```